# Responsive image not responding the way it should

Tags: html, image, css, responsive

I created a web site with a background image in its header. I placed the image in the CSS stylesheet. The image responds nicely in its width, but the height doesn't. You can view the site here: www.devcore.tech

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="introduction">
    <h1>Tecnología al alcance de todos.</h1>
    <form action="nosotros.html">
    <input class="introduction-button" type="submit" 
    value="Conócenos" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.introduction {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #102a42;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #102a42 0%, #171c31 
    100%);
    background-image: url(../images/geometry.png); /* Image size 1280 x 1024px*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's working according to `background-size:contain;`. What seems to be going wrong and behavior do you want instead?

Comment: @showdev If you resize the window, you'll see that the image shrinks correctly from side to side. However, you'll see blue space on top and below the image. I want the image to take full height as well.

Comment: @showdev here is a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4z6yo93k1dq5mz/Screen%20Shot%202018-03-13%20at%204.07.22%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: That's what `background-size:contain` does. Maybe you'd prefer `cover`? [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/kx9ddmxn/1/).

Comment: @showdev Thanks again, but it still doesn't work. I think I'll leave it as it is for now, until the site's next release soon :) Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

What is you change your `padding: 20px` on the `.introduction-button` to `padding: 2%` instead? should scale roughly to what you need.

Comment: `background-size: cover` vs `contain` should work as well, it depends on how picky you are.

Comment: Thanks. Still not working. Any other thoughts? I'm out of ideas! :)

Comment: i don't; `background-size: cover` works when i view it, if you need to get super specific, you'll have to photoshop your desired result, 'cause `cover` will take out that empty blue space you had marked up.

Comment: if I were to edit the image in Photoshop, how big would the image have to be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add to the css:

```
height: auto;
```

Comment: Thanks @James but it still doesn't work. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For a background image issue, use **background-size:cover** css;

Also, refer this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/korahlucky6/owst3j5k/1/

```css
.introduction {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #102a42;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #102a42 0%, #171c31 
    100%);
    background-image: url("https://www.welovesolo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/p16hh38qpn1ksms08j6e1c1r61d9-details.jpg"); /* Image size 1280 x 1024px*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="introduction">
    <h1>Tecnología al alcance de todos.</h1>
    <form action="nosotros.html">
    <input class="introduction-button" type="submit" 
    value="Conócenos" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've already solved this issue. What I did was create a larger image in Photoshop, and it worked with the code above. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply :-)